# Redirecting to the invalid URI. Jenkins in a docker container behind the Nginx

Tags: docker, nginx, jenkins

Successfully pulled an image from the official Jenkins hub and run a container with the following parameters

```
docker run -d --name=jenkins -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 -e JENKINS_OPTS="--prefix=/build" -v jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home jenkins/jenkins:lts
```

Also, I have the Nginx installed on my host (**not a container!**)

Instructions for Nginx

```
upstream jenkins {
        server localhost:8080;
        keepalive 16;
}

server {
        listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
        listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot

        server_name example.com www.example.com;

        ignore_invalid_headers off;

        location /build/ {
                proxy_pass http://jenkins;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_redirect default;

                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header Connection "";
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto: $scheme;

                client_max_body_size 10m;
                client_body_buffer_size 128k;

                proxy_connect_timeout 90;
                proxy_send_timeout 90;
                proxy_read_timeout 90;
                proxy_buffering off;
                proxy_request_buffering off;
        }

        access_log /var/log/nginx/jenkins.access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/jenkins.error.log;

        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
        include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
server {
        listen 80;
        return 301 https://example.comk$request_uri;
}
```

Trying to access Jenkins via https://example.com/build. It asks me to input an initial admin password. After successfull submission it gives me this page

[Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UOrpF.png) URL is https://example.com/build/:%20https://example:80/build/

I tried to add prefix... Tried to restart both of them but nothing changes.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put **set_proxy_headers** strings before the **proxy_pass**. Such as

```
location /build/ {
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Connection "";
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto: $scheme;

            proxy_pass http://jenkins;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_redirect default;

            client_max_body_size 10m;
            client_body_buffer_size 128k;

            proxy_connect_timeout 90;
            proxy_send_timeout 90;
            proxy_read_timeout 90;
            proxy_buffering off;
            proxy_request_buffering off;
    }
```